# Why /proc has nosuid on Ubuntu

Tags: mount, proc, suid

I notice /proc and /dev is mounted differently on ubuntu than other linux distribution as follows:

Ubuntu:

```
udev on /dev type devtmpfs (rw,nosuid,relatime,size=4079136k,nr_inodes=1019784,mode=755)  
proc on /proc type proc (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime)
```

ALinux:

```
devtmpfs on /dev type devtmpfs (rw,relatime,size=1015576k,nr_inodes=253894,mode=755)  
proc on /proc type proc (rw,relatime)
```

I know nosuid is a security option to disallow files that contain setuid flag. But isn't /proc is a virtual file system already, and /proc serves as a interface to query kernal information. Why is /proc still needed to be mounted with **nosuid**? Similarly to /dev.

Please let me know.

Answer (score 1):

1 word.  Security.  As a general rule, you should only give enough permissions to get the job done.  Allowing setuid on stuff in /proc makes no sense... therefore... don't allow it.  All it would potentially do is create an attack surface to exploit your system.